# Is this verbless clause 'when a student at Harvard' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Someone mentioned that *"with children's books and DVDs equally second at 20% each"* in the following sentence from another [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13180/why-is-this-sentence-correct) is a **verbless adverbial clause**.

> In 2005, fiction made up the largest proportion of items borrowed at 35% **with children's books and DVDs equally second at 20% each**.

Actually, I would like to ask if it is or it is not qualified as a *verbless adverbial clause* there, but I don't want to make that question lose its focus. (If you can clear that point here too, I will be grateful. To me, it looks like one.)

So I searched for the definition of *verbless adverbial clause*, and this [link at About.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/verblessclauseterm.htm) came up. I was surprised to see these examples there,

> The following sentences contain further examples of verbless clauses (italicized):
>   (38) He considered *the girl a good student*.
>   (39) *Whenever in trouble*, Bill rang his girl-friend.
>   (40) He married her **when a student at Harvard**.

I've no problems with other examples but (40). The (40) sounds very odd. It was mentioned that the examples were taken from (Herman Wekker and Liliane M. V. Haegeman, *A Modern Course in English Syntax*. Taylor & Francis, 1985), and I could find its PDF at [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/AModernCourseInEnglishSyntax-HermanWekkerLilianeHaegeman), so I can confirm that the example (40) has no misspelling nor omissions.

Is the sentence *"He married her when a student at Harvard,"* grammatically correct, according to today's English grammar?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with that use of *when*, but I tend to use while. In informal contexts, I slip into *when* all of the time, and I often find myself correcting it. But there is no real need to do so other than speaker's preference. *When* and *while* are both temporal, and both mean *during* or *at that time*. *While* has additional meanings, but they're the same here.

Comment: @JohnQPublic From a non-native speaker point of view (and I believe that many other non-native speakers will agree with me), the choice between when/while is not as odd-looking as the missing of "he was" (or "she was?") in this example. However, according to J.R.'s answer and your comment, it appears to me that this omission is actually perfectly normal for native speakers.

Comment: LOL I was writing up an explanation **while** (conjunction) you were choosing. It's just elision. See my answer below if you're still unsure.

Comment: I should note that you're **not required to elide the extra *he was*** in that sentence. Although you're free to include it **for effect**, it is, in essence **redundant**, which is why most native speakers would exclude it. Make sense?

Comment: @JohnQPublic Thank you very much. Though it's not a verbless adverbial clause, it's still a verbless clause, where the elision is "he was", am I correct? (Note that "the girl a good student" makes perfect sense to me, but I will need a while before "when a student at Harvard" sinks in.)

Comment: @JohnQPublic I meant that "the girl a good student" part in one the example sentences, but I understand you. Most of the time elisions make sense. Perhaps I'm just not familiar with this type of elision (where "he was" is elided). Thank you for making things much clearer to me now.

Comment: Yes, you understand. Sorry, I should have looked up, because I missed that completely. It's still a different type of elision. Where in one sentence, it's the subject and verb, in *the girl a good student*, it's part of the direct object that's being elided, which is the infinitive *to be*, not a verb. *He (subj) considered (verb) the girl **to be** (elided) a good student* (direct object -- *He considered what? **Her to be a good student***) That's the case of one long object phrase being elided.

Comment: *Consider* probably doesn't take a small clause complement.  It can't be a single constituent, as it fails any constituent test you can think of: \*"The girl [to be] a good student he considered", \*"It was the girl [to be] a good student that he considered", etc.  It's more likely that *the girl* and *a good student* are separate arguments of *consider*.  Contrast this with "While [he was] a student at Harvard, he married her" or "It was while [he was] a student at Harvard that he married her".  38 has a different structure than 39 and 40, in my opinion.

Comment: @snailboat Passive voice: ***The girl was considered to be a good student** by him*. I know I'll catch a lot of flack for that not being the classic passive construction, but it's passive voice nonetheless.

Comment: @JohnQPublic I gave a couple constituent tests (fronting, clefting) which apply differently to 38 than to 39 and 40.  If we apply a passivization test, then we need to turn our putative object ("the girl [to be] a good student") into the subject.  You can't write a passive form with "The girl [to be] a good student" as a subject: \*"The girl [to be] a good student was considered by him." is ungrammatical.  Thus a passivization test too shows that it is not a single constituent and therefore cannot be an object.  (This is not the same thing as saying the passive cannot be written.)

Comment: @snailboat I stand corrected. I was too busy trying to force *to be* into it to notice my error. As you noted, I made the indirect, rather than direct object into the agent of action. The unwieldy passive would be *To be a good student the girl was considered by him.* With that said, *the girl a good student* is, to my ear, existential, which would indicate a copula. While my comment was incorrect, I cannot see this as grammatical in any other light This is not an attempt to lure you into an argument; I'm just stumped by the grammar of 38. I know it's grammatical, but am stumped as to why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use *while* instead of *when*:

> He married her while a student at Harvard.

Moreover, the sentence has some built-in ambiguity – did the wedding take place when ***he*** was a student at Harvard, or while ***she*** was studying there? There's room for interpretation either way, although additional context could render that point moot.

Casting those reservations aside, however, and getting back to your original question: I can find no grammatical errors in the original that you quoted. That said, the sentence does seem a bit concise, and I wouldn't really expect to hear it in conversation. Grammatically, it has the feel of newspaper headline; I think that:

> "He married her while he was a student at Harvard."

would be something my friends would be more likely to say.

Comment: +1 you took the words right out of my mouth, which is no small feat. I think that *when* is grammatical, but it just sounds better as *while*. I would disagree about the ambiguity in the first example however. Because this is active voice, and because he is the subject and is thus taking the action, the complement can only refer to the subject in (i.e. in **my mind** at least).

Comment: @J.R. while is better because there was an extent of time during which he was a student, and he married at some point in that time: the word while more specifically indicates this sense. When indicates it too, but it also indicates when short events coincide. "He married her {when | *while} he moved out East." When both "when" and "while" are possible and have the same interpretation, "while" is tighter, in some sense.

Comment: @J.R. I don't seem to perceive that there is much room for the "she-student" interpretation so much so that sentences of this pattern which force me to take the interpretation semantically bother my ear.  Does the choice of "while" versus "when" influence your perception of the existence of an ambiguity, or would you say it is independent of that choice?

Comment: @Kaz I believe the difference in connotation between *when* and *while* is much less significant than we might think. The four definitions I linked in my answer are nearly verbatim (i.e. where they are the same parts of speech). The bizarre thing is that, while I agree with both you and J.R., M-W does not agree with us. It's a distinction so fine that I find myself unable to define the difference. At the end of the day though, I don't think there's any real problem with substituting one for the other when they are same part of speech. The other definitions of *while* are more problematic.

Comment: @JohnQ - Just because two words _can_ mean the same thing doesn't mean both will sound as natural in a certain context. I recommended _while_ because it sounds more natural, not because _when_ is wrong. It's not unlike _I met my son at the lobby_ – sure, I CAN say that (no arguments from the dictionary), but I would probably use _in_ there instead: _I met my son in the lobby_.

Comment: @Kaz - I understand that by parsing the original sentence, one can deduce that _he_ is the student at Harvard. In conversation, though, we don't get to go back and exampine the sentence and see what the subject is. What I called "ambiguity" isn't tied to _when_ or _while_, it's tied to location and proximity of the words. I'm reminded of Groucho's famous line: _"The other day I shot an elephant in my pajamas... How he got into my pajamas I'll never know."_ (That's not a perfect analogy, but to the _listener_, I still think there's room for some confusion.) As the O.P. wrote, it "sounds odd."

Comment: @J.R. I actually did agree with this comment above. And I agree with your example here too. That said, prepositions are slightly different. *I'm going to be in Brooklyn **at** the weekend.* v. *I'm going to be in Brooklyn **on** the weekend.* Which is correct? I'd say *on*, Brits would say *at*. My point is, this may be dialect driven. I'd maintain that *at the weekend* is unnatural, but British speakers might say otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I know that while [*when*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/when%5B2%5D) can be an adverb, it's actually used as a conjunction in number 40 (with a touch of elision to boot).

[*When*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when), in this case, means *during the time at/through which*. It's actually two independent clauses, with one elided, and when joining them.

> He married her when he was at Harvard.
>
> He married her. When he was at Harvard, he married her.

I suspect that many native speaker's prefer [*while*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/while%5B1%5D), but in this usage [*while*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/while) is **still** a **conjunction** joining independent clauses. The only difference between *while* and *when* is that *while* is **never** an adverb (it can be a noun, a verb, preposition or conjunction, but not an adverb).

> He married her while he was a student at Harvard.
>
> He married her. While he was a student at Harvard, he married her.

Because these words are semantically related, and because they're both conjunctions here, they are interchangeable.

Native speakers are inclined to omit the extra *he was* because it's redundant. The agent of action (subject) and the recipient of the action (direct object) are abundantly clear, so we can fill in the blanks, so to speak.

I disagree, however, that it's a *verbless adverbial clause*.

Answer (score 1):

> He married her when a student at Harvard.

This can be understood as just another case of elision.

Hypothesis:

> He married her when **he was** a student at Harvard. ["he was" is removable.]

Interestingly, this interpretation wouldn't be made.

> * He married her when **she was** a student at Harvard.

Though it is possible for a similar elision to target the object rather than the subject, when the semantics allows only that interpretation, but it is odd:

> * He got that dog when still a puppy. [when that dog was still a puppy.]

My ear doesn't like it that the object "that dog" is being elided, and that I'm forced to take that interpretation by the semantics.

> He got that dog {*when | ?? while | as} a puppy.

While seems somewhat more acceptable compared to when, but I'm not able to articulate a plausible hypothesis why.

Regarding "as", note that if we have:

> He married her **as** a student at Harvard.

It is now ambiguous: was she the student or he?

Moreover, **it is no longer elision**. "as a student" is a complete phrase. We don't know whether it modifies "her" (she as a student) or the action (he married as a student).

The sentence:

> He got that dog as a puppy.

also has the grammatic ambiguity, but we interpret it the only way it makes sense. Either interpretation has comfortable grammar: there isn't the conflict of having to choose the sensible meaning, yet being uncomfortable with the grammatic structure which that meaning requires.

Comment: I've got no major objections to your answer, but , I believe you've clarified something that I was unable to articulate. I knew *when* and *while* are only interchangeable when they represent the same part of speech, but I hadn't considered how closely related they are even when not so. I believe that in *He got that dog while a puppy* is using *while* as a preposition, which is why it's so easily replaced by *as*. And interestingly, while the *as* in *He married her **as** a student at Harvard* could function as a preposition, I read it as being a conjunction too, with *he was* elided.

Comment: *He married her **as/while/when** a student at Harvard* can all be read with the words in bold type as being conjunctions--with essentially the same meanings--and with *he was* elided from the relative clause. However, as you smartly point out, *as* could very well be a preposition in that sentence, thus creating some ambiguity. *When/while* both provide a temporal sense that reduces that ambiguity. But what's the precise difference between these two (genuine curiosity)? I'd never had reason to give this much thought, so I'm struggling to discern a difference in meaning in a conjunctive sense.